# Can PHP read server HTTP logs?

Tags: php, logging

I'd like to easily access the logs of a server to interpret them in a way and display that data to a website visitor. How can PHP access the HTTP logs of a server and all data therein?

Comment: Please pay attention to the suggest prompts when tagging your question.  Any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong. Avoid creating new tags.

Comment: But there's a whole badge for creating popular tags, called Taxonomist -- see http://stackoverflow.com/badges -- so it appears one IS allowed to create new tags!

Comment: If they are _good_ tags, but you should really try to fit into existing categories first if you can.  Users with < 100 rep aren't allowed to create tags at all any more.

Comment: I was simple creating "good" tags. Such as "server-logs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way: create a symbolic link from /var/log/apache2/{acces,error,...}.log to a readable dir, e.g: /var/www

Comment: Notice 2 details:
1) PHP can acces folder before content of www. So it's better to have the symlink dest before www to avoid user to open it in browser. in PHP you can simply acces it with one more "../". Eg if you file is "test.log" and you php sript is at http://www.domaine.com/script.php, it will acces the fil using "../test.log"
2) You must change the right of the original file. Meaning in your terminal, perform a chmod 744 on the original file. In the other case, PHP will not be allowed to read the file, even through the symlink.

Answer (score 3):

The server logs are generally just a file that you can read and parse as any other file. Reading it line by line and using `split` or a regular expression are commonly done.

These can get quite large, though, so it's not unusual to have a separate process that runs once a day or an hour or whatever that updates a summary file, which would then be read by your PHP script. Or often the separate process generates static HTML pages that then just get served. There are many log analyzers that work this way.